# Moving Google Chart column annotation position

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using the below code to produce a column chart with the figures inside the columns, but I'd really like them to be positioned at the bottom of the bars and not the top.

Here's a visual of the chart I have:

[image: google chart with annotations]

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Type', 'Completed', 'Outstanding'],
        ['Item 1', 75, 25],
        ['Item 2', 50, 40],
        ['Item 3', 80, 15]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,
        {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        },
        2,
        {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 2,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        }]);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        height: 270,
        chartArea: { 'width': '80%', 'height': '80%' },
        bar: { groupWidth: '80%' },
        vAxis: {
            textPosition: 'none',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }
        },
      series: {
          0: { color: '#00A887' },
          1: { color: '#F6323E' },
        }

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('northPMChart'));

    chart.draw(view, options);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are no standard [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) for moving annotations to the bottom

you can adjust `annotations.stem.length` to adjust from the default position

but this will move all the annotations the same distance,

which would not work here

---

you can manually move the annotations, as in the following snippet...

however, custom modifications will not be reflected when using `getImageURI`,
if you need to produce a png image of the chart

also, the chart will move the annotations back to their original location,
anytime there interactivity, such as column hover

so must use a `MutationObserver` to move them back, when activity occurs...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Type', 'Completed', 'Outstanding'],
        ['Item 1', 75, 25],
        ['Item 2', 50, 40],
        ['Item 3', 80, 15]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,
        {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        },
        2,
        {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 2,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        }]);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        height: 270,
        chartArea: { 'width': '80%', 'height': '80%' },
        bar: { groupWidth: '80%' },
        vAxis: {
            textPosition: 'none',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }
        },
      series: {
          0: { color: '#00A887' },
          1: { color: '#F6323E' },
        }

    };

    var container = document.getElementById('northPMChart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

    // move annotations
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(annotation) {
        if ((annotation.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') &&
            (annotation.getAttribute('fill') === '#ffffff')) {
          var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
          annotation.setAttribute('y',
            chartLayout.getYLocation(0) - (parseInt(annotation.getAttribute('font-size')) / 2)
          );
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });

    chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="northPMChart"></div>
```

Comment: That's excellent many thanks. Also it doesn't appear to move back on hover when I try which is great.