# Is it possible to add an alternating background color and some text on an area chart on Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would simply like to make this :

[image: Initial Graph]

Looking like this :

[image: Finial Graph I want to look like]

Here, I've made the 2nd pic with Photoshop, but is it possible to make a graph looking like that with Google Chart ?
If yes, what are the functionnalities I should use ?

Comment: it's possible, use additional area series for the background colors and [annotations](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole) for the text -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39671447/5090771) of using area series for the background...

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'll try it tomorrow ;)

Comment: to move certain annotations, place the annotations option inside the series option and change the stem length -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51635726/5090771) for an example...