# google charts move annotation position to center of stacked chart

Tags: charts, annotations, position, google-visualization, stacked

I am using Google Chart's column graph chart. The chart is a stacked column chart with annotations for every data point of the stacked column. The annotation are at the top of the inside of the bar but I would like them to be centred inside of the bar. The closest solution I found was moving the annotation of a non stacked column google chart to the bottom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845104/moving-google-chart-column-annotation-position).

The problem with this solution is that the code looks for annotation that are white and moves them to the bottom. The graph I am working on has multiple colours for the annotations and all the annotation of that colour move to the top vs the centre of the subset of the stacked column.

```
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Range', 'score range A',{role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' }, 'score range B',{role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' }, 'score range C', {role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' },'score range D', {role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' }],
      ['Range', 4,'#D7F0B4','0-4',6,'#00B050','5-10',9,'#92D050','11-19',6, '#AAE182','20-25']
    ]);

    var options = {
      vAxis:{ ticks: [0,4,10,19], viewWindow: { max: 25} },
      isStacked: true,
      title: 'Score',
      legend: {position: 'none'}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('idealchartA'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

@Whitehat solved the above problem but when I another column with some of the annotation values as null the positioning gets thrown off.

here is the new data series I tried to add
`['Range', 4,'#D7F0B4','0-4',6,'#00B050','5-10',9,'#92D050','11-19',6, '#AAE182','20-25'], ['Yours', 4,'white; fill-opacity: 0',null,6, '#00B050',10, 9,'white; fill-opacity: 0',null,6,'white; fill-opacity: 0',null]`.

The idea is to have a graph like the attached image below but with the annotations centred.
[image: Ideal stacked graph without the text centred]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar to the other question, just need to a way to find the annotations.
here, we use the `text-anchor` attribute, assuming it isn't the x-axis label.

then we can use chart method `getChartLayoutInterface` to calculate the new position.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Range', 'score range A',{role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' }, 'score range B',{role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' }, 'score range C', {role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' },'score range D', {role: 'style'},{ role: 'annotation' }],
    ['Range', 4,'#D7F0B4','0-4',6,'#00B050','5-10',9,'#92D050','11-19',6, '#AAE182','20-25']
  ]);

  var options = {
    vAxis:{ ticks: [0,4,10,19], viewWindow: { max: 25} },
    isStacked: true,
    title: 'Score',
    legend: {position: 'none'}
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('idealchartA');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(moveAnnotations);
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  function moveAnnotations() {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var barBounds;
    var labelBounds;
    var yAdj;

    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var index = 0;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if ((label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') && (label.textContent !== data.getValue(0, 0))) {
        barBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#' + index + '#0');
        labelBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('annotationtext#' + index + '#0#0');
        yAdj = (barBounds.height / 2) + (parseFloat(label.getAttribute('font-size')) / 2) - 2;
        label.setAttribute('y', barBounds.top + yAdj);
        index++;
      }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="idealchartA"></div>
```

Comment: I added a new stacked column with null values as annotation but this threw the javascript off because it can calculate the distance for null. 

      ['Range', 4,'#D7F0B4','0-4',6,'#00B050','5-10',9,'#92D050','11-19',6, '#AAE182','20-25'],
      ['Yours', 4,'white; fill-opacity: 0',null,6, '#00B050',10, 9,'white; fill-opacity: 0',null,6,'white; fill-opacity: 0',null]