# Google Charts annotation Position Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I want annotation text to be shown inside a graph to be on the left position but its showing on the right side of graph. Kindly suggest how to align it on the left side.

Image shows `Cu`, `Ag`, and `Au` right side of the bar, but I want them on left side of bar

[image: Image shows cu,ag,Au,Pt on right , I want them on left side of bar]

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
         ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', 'Cu' ],
         ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver', 'Ag' ],
         ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold', 'Au' ],
         ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2', 'Pt' ]
      ]);

Comment: this is refernce link for google charts which i am using-https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#bar-styles

Comment: no options out of the box for positioning annotations, but you can move them manually on the chart's `'ready'` event. [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846554/5090771), using a ColumnChart, solution would be similar here...