# Google Charts - Make a Column Chart so that positive values show above their columns, and negative values below their column

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Assume the following Google Chart:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Load the Google Charts library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Category', 'Value', { role: 'annotation' }],
        ['Category 1', 10, 10],
        ['Category 2', -5, -5],
        ['Category 3', 8, 8],
        ['Category 4', -3, -3],
        ['Category 5', 12, 12]
      ]);

      // Add a calculated annotation role for positioning
      data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});

      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        var value = data.getValue(i, 1);
        if (value >= 0) {
          data.setValue(i, 2, value);
          data.setValue(i, 3, 'above');
        } else {
          data.setValue(i, 2, value);
          data.setValue(i, 3, 'below');
        }
      }

      var options = {
        title: 'Horizontal Bar Chart with Positive and Negative Values',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        vAxis: { title: 'Category' },
        hAxis: { minValue: -15, maxValue: 15 },
        annotations: {
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 12,
            bold: true,
          },
          annotationRole: 'annotationText', // Use the calculated annotation role
          annotationPosition: 'out', // Place annotations outside the bar
        },
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Create a div element to hold the chart -->
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to modify the code so that on Categories 1, 3 and 5 (where their values is a positive number), each value will be above the column (like `alwaysOutside: true` does), while on the 2 other Categories, where their values are negative numbers, I wanted for their values to appear **below** their column (i.e. in between the column and "Category 2"). [Just like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh5BM.png)

Comment: there are no config options for setting annotation position, other than `alwaysOutside`. but you can manually move the annotations, after the chart has been drawn. for an example, see [Moving Google Chart column annotation position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846554/5090771)